# Issues parsing dates for a while loop in Android

Tags: android, date, while-loop, calendar

I'm currently prototyping an app that calculates vacation costs based on check in and check out date. The idea is that once the dates are submitted a While loop runs until the check out date is reached. However, I can't seem to get the Calendar dates to parse correctly. In a recent test I entered a check in date of 2/20/2015 and check out of 2/22/2015 and both were logged as 1-2-5 in logcat.

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    final DatePicker datePickerCheckIn = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerCheckIn);
    final DatePicker datePickerCheckOut = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerCheckOut);

    final TextView studioTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.studioTotal);
    final TextView oneBedTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneBedTotal);
    final TextView twoBedTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twoBedTotal);
    final TextView villaTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.villaTotal);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    //Set check in values
            int checkInDay = datePickerCheckIn.getDayOfMonth();
            int checkInMonth = datePickerCheckIn.getMonth();
            checkInMonth = checkInMonth + 1;                
            int checkInYear = datePickerCheckIn.getYear();


    //Set check out values
            int checkOutDay = datePickerCheckOut.getDayOfMonth();
            int checkOutMonth = datePickerCheckOut.getMonth();
            checkOutMonth = checkOutMonth + 1;
            int checkOutYear = datePickerCheckOut.getYear();


    //Reset rates
            studioTotalPoints = 0;
            oneBedTotalPoints = 0;
            twoBedTotalPoints = 0;
            villaTotalPoints = 0;

            final String checkInStart = checkInYear+"-"+checkInMonth+"-"+checkInDay;
            final String checkOutEnd = checkOutYear+"-"+checkOutMonth+"-"+checkOutDay;

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar dateStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                dateStart.setTime(sdf.parse(checkInStart));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Calendar dateEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                dateEnd.setTime(sdf.parse(checkOutEnd));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("Start Date: ", dateStart.YEAR+"-"+dateStart.MONTH+"-"+dateStart.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Log.i("End Date: ", dateEnd.YEAR+"-"+dateEnd.MONTH+"-"+dateEnd.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            while (dateStart.DAY_OF_YEAR < dateEnd.DAY_OF_YEAR)
            {
                studioTotalPoints += rateStudioA1;
                oneBedTotalPoints += rate1BedA1;
                twoBedTotalPoints += rate2BedA1;
                villaTotalPoints += rateVillaA1;

                dateStart.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                Log.i("Dates", dateStart+"-"+dateEnd);

                totalNights +=1;
            }

            studioTotal.setText(""+studioTotalPoints);
            oneBedTotal.setText(""+oneBedTotalPoints);
            twoBedTotal.setText(""+twoBedTotalPoints);
            villaTotal.setText(""+villaTotalPoints);
        }
    };



    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

There seems to be something wrong with how the dates are parsed from the datepickers to the Calendar, but I'm not sure what it is.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
String checkInStart = checkInYear+"-"+checkInMonth+"-"+checkInDay;
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date startDate;
try {
    startDate = sdf.parse(checkInStart);
    String newDateString = sdf.format(startDate);
    System.out.println(newDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for correct parsing of the string.